# In a Riemann Integral, is a partition just a set of disjoint open/semiopen intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

In the Riemann integral section, my book says:

> A Partition of $[a, b]$ is any finite subset $P$ having the form
>
> $$P = \{a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n = b \}$$

I have never seen this notation before. Is a partition just a set of disjoint open/semiopen intervals, all of which are subsets of $[a, b]$? For example, is $\{[0, 2), (2, 6), (6, 10]\}$ a partition of  $[0, 10]$?

Comment: Just add the term **disjoint** open/semi-open

Comment: And yes the above is a partition of $[0,10]$

Comment: @learnmore Ok added :)

Comment: So what's your problem regarding that definition

Comment: @learnmore Ah it's just that I've never seen that notation before and I wanted to make sure I know exactly what it means. I would've written it as $P = \{ t \in \mathbb{R} : a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n = b \}$

Comment: @Nico Yes I believe my example of  $\{[0, 2), (2, 6), (6, 10]\}$ being a partition of $[0, 10]$ satisfies that, but user389056 disagrees that it is a partition. (edit: never mind, the user has deleted the comment)

Comment: @Ovi After looking into it further, I think it depends on the book. The way my lecture notes define a partition states that the union of all your intervals must be the whole set you're partitioning, but apparently other sources do not have this requirement.

Comment: @learnmore Oops nevermind I just glanced over my notation and I see it makes no sense haha.

Comment: @user389056 Hmm interesting, I will look into it further.

Comment: @Ovi Rudin has it that a $partition$ of $[a,b]$ is a finite set of points where $a = x_0 \leq x_1 \leq \ldots \leq x_{n-1} \leq x_n = b$, so apparently he requires neither disjoint nor the union.

Comment: @user389056 Okay thanks for getting back to me with that, I have that book as well and I'll compare the two definitions. The definition in the OP comes from Kenneth Ross' *Elementary Analysis*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't quite accurate. The partition is the set of *points* $\{t_0, t_1, . . . , t_n\}$, and we think of this as *representing* the (not-quite-disjoint) intervals $[t_0, t_1], [t_1, t_2], . . . , [t_{n-1}, t_n]$.

The notation $$P=\{a=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=b\}$$ just means that $P$ is a set of $n+1$-many distinct elements, the least of which is $a$ and the greatest of which is $b$; it also fixes the notation that we label those points in order.

Comment: +1. Also OP, Note that the strict $<$ is not necessary for the definition to work with the integral, as if $t_i=t_{i+1}$ then $\delta t_{i}=0$ and the contribution to the sum is $0$.

Comment: What happens if you take it to mean a "disjoint" partition. Surely there will be some open intervals and half open intervals involved. So would it not affect Integrability? (I think it should, my reason— for instance $\sup f$ on $[t_{k-1},t_k]$ and $(t_{k-1}, t_k)$ need not be same. So...)